# Refresh value from ngrx store after delay, best approach...?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using the code below in my Angular app to show a loading spinner.

It selects the isLoaded value from the store, pipes to delay(500) and then refreshes the value of isLoaded from the store, this is so that the spinner only shows **if still necessary after 500ms**... during which time data would normally be loaded and isLoaded would become true, therefore no flickering of the loading spinner for a very short duration.

I feel like there is probably a better way of doing this...?

Is the first call to `select(selectUserIsLoaded)` even necessary, could I just start the pipe with the delay(500), then do `select(selectUserIsLoaded)`? Is it necessary to use the switchMap operator to refresh the value?

```
// loading spinner element has *ngIf="!isLoaded"
isLoaded: boolean = false; 

// code located in ngOnInit()
this._store
    .pipe(
        select(selectUserIsLoaded),
        delay(500),
        switchMap(() =>
            this._store
                .select(selectUserIsLoaded)
        )
    )
    .subscribe((isLoaded) => (this.isLoaded = isLoaded));
```

Comment: Manually slowing the app by 500 feels wrong. If the flickering spinner annoys you, maybe use a different spinner like a line on top of the page

Comment: Dismiss the spinner purely in your UI and leave the state as is -  consider you are setting 'user is loaded' to false - but your user is still loaded.